# Not able to call a callback method in kendo mobile datasourse

Tags: asp.net, kendo-mobile

Here is my code for kendo mobile ui datasourse

```
var pdata = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: '@Url.Content("~/Message/GetList")',
          type: "post",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }
    });

I Bind this datasourse to a listview template 


    $("#inbox").kendoMobileListView({
                dataSource: pdata
                template: $("#inboxItem").text(),

            })
```

Now I need a callback function which is called after listview template is bind through datasourse.
If I simply call my function  after this code the function is called before the template is bind because of asynchronous nature of ajax hit to the server .How to implement callback functionality here .I dont want to use delay here to call my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dataBound event of ListView for this:

```
$("#inbox").kendoMobileListView({
                dataSource: pdata
                template: $("#inboxItem").text(),
                dataBound: function(e){
                alert('Now the listview received data from the datasource');

}
            })
```